# Store state of a JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, closures

Im trying to store the stats of 'this' in my javscript object so that later on in my application I can return 'this' to a previous state. I thought I could accomplish using a closure but so far I haven't successful. My idea was to do something like this

```
function SavedFeature() {
    var self = this;

    this.savedItem;

    this.storeState = function() {
        this.savedItem = storeClosure();
    }

    function storeClosure() {
        var closure = self;
        return function() {
            return closure;
        };
    };

    //other things the user can change...
}
```

so later on in my application if I needed to return to the point when I called storeState I could just do

```
//return the object I put in my closure
var backToNormal = savedFeature.savedItem();
```

that doesn't work though because any changes to my savedFeature object after I call storeState() are being reflected in the item im retrieving from called savedItem(). I'm guessing this is happening because closure is being set to a reference of self instead of copied to a new instance.

Is there anyway to store the state of my entire object in a closure like this or do I need to store this some other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are running into is that in js objects are passed by reference. This means that all changes performed on your object will apply to your `obj.savedItem` property.

**Fix: Store a deep clone into `obj.savedItem`**

```
 this.storeState = function() {
     this.savedItem = _.cloneDeep(this); // or _.clone(this, true);
 }
```

`cloneDeep` is a [lodash](http://lodash.com/) method, most js libs supply one of their own, e.g. jQuery's [$.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/), etc.

You could easily roll your own deep clone function, look up the options on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object/122704#122704).

**A complete example with jQuery:**

```
function SavedFeature() {
    this.savedItem;

    this.clone = function() {
       return $.extend(true, {}, this);
    },

    this.storeState = function() {
        this.savedItem = this.clone();
    }
}
```

Doing it this way allows you adapt to different environments by changing your `clone` method as it is facading the used library method.

Comment: Seems like deep copying is the only way to get this done for an entire object.

Answer (score 2):

There are dozens of ways how to implement it. I will do just simple one. saving property. 
Take into account *if you want to save entire object you need to do deep copy of the object*.

this is your feature:

```
function SavedFeature() {
        this.savedItem = {'isNew': true};
        this.stateMachine = new StateMachine();
}
```

this is some kind of state machine:

```
function StateMachine () {
      var state = { 'isNew' : null};
      function set(newState) {
         state.isNew = newState.isNew;
      }
      function get() {
         return state.isNew;
      }
      return {
      get : get,
      set : set
      };
    }
```

which, know how to store **isNew** property

and a working sample:

```
 var savedFeature = new SavedFeature();
 console.log(savedFeature.savedItem); //  true by default

 savedFeature.stateMachine.set(savedFeature.savedItem); // saving state.
 savedFeature.savedItem.isNew = false; // modifying state
 console.log(savedFeature.savedItem); // return false, because of statement above

 var restoredState = savedFeature.stateMachine.get(); // restoring state
 console.log(restoredState); // true

 savedFeature.savedItem.isNew = restoredState.isNew;
 console.log(savedFeature.savedItem); // true
```

you can adjust that code, and reach functionality whatever you need. hope that helps